# How far can you increment a 32bit float?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, precision

If you incremented a float by one over and over again, starting at `0`, where would it stop?

```
float myfloat = 0.0;
float lastfloat = -1;
while(lastfloat != myfloat) {
    lastfloat = myfloat;
    myfloat += 1.0;
}
cout << "myfloat: " << myfloat << endl;
```

Clarification: by stop, I ment where would the value of the float stop to change. At some point, the float reaches a value so that it cannot represent a value one higher. I want to know this value. I cannot binary search it because there's not a clear cut difference, and running the code to find out probably takes a really long time, especially for a 64bit float.

Comment: You have the code; what happened when you ran it?  You did run it, right?

Comment: @ScottHunter He mentioned the difficulty with just running it above. Besides which, observing the outcome wouldn't trivially explain the outcome.

Comment: @Sneftel: That was *after* my comment.  Also, that wasn't the original code, either.

Comment: @ScottHunter Ah, got it.

Answer (score 2):

If will never stop; eventually, `myfloat` will be so big that adding 1 to it won't change it (in case you were hoping to stop the loop by some kind of overflow error).  As you have no other mechanism for stopping the loop, it won't.

Comment: Interestingly, IEEE 754 allows for directed rounding as an implementation option. If the system was set to round up, it would get all the way to +INF before staying the same. (And if floating point exceptions were enabled, the loop could even terminate, though presumably not in the way the OP anticipated.)

Comment: The question isn't if, but when :)

Comment: I don't understand the answer, as you said yourself, you have the code, didn't you run it? Or was the question edited after the answer?

Comment: @aka.nice: the question was edited after I answered.

Answer (score -1):

The regular signed float has the following segmentation of the bytes:

- 1 bit for the sign
- 8 bits for the exponent
- 23 bits for the fraction

The amount of increments of 1 that you will have to go through will be 2^8 bits which equates to 
**2^(16*8-1) = 1.7014*10^38**

You will have to iterate 1.704*10^38 times before it will then go back to the negative side of the float which is 
**2^-(16*8-2) = 1.1754^38**

Comment: Except it wouldn't. Once the number gets to 2^24, adding 1 will have no effect. And also, floating point arithmetic doesn't wrap around.